# Validating residual plot count data (different levels)

Tags: residuals, negative-binomial-distribution, count-data, validation

I am studying the distribution of a marine species using the number of sightings as a dependent variable. When I am trying to validate the plots of the best model I am getting a non-usual pattern, and then I decided to get the null model with different distributions, and I don’t know what is causing the different levels on the residuals vs fitted values.

[image]

```
null<-glm.nb(Sightings~offset(logEffortScale),data=l, link=log)
```

[image]

```
null<-glm.nb(Sightings~offset(logEffortScale),data=l, link=log)

plot(residuals(null)~predict(null))
```

[image]

**Edit: correct residuals vs predicted plot**

```
plot(residuals(null)~predict(null,type="response"))
```

[image]

```
m1 <- zeroinfl(Sightings ~ offset(logEffortScale), data = l)
```

[image]

```
m1b <- zeroinfl(Sightings ~ offset(logEffortScale), data = l, dist = "negbin")
```

[image]

```
m2 <- zeroinfl(Sightings ~ offset(logEffortScale), data = l, dist='poisson', link='logit')
```

[image]

Comment: What's the difficulty? Are you concerned about the curved lines in the residual plot? That's a natural consequence of the discrete data and the model you're fitting.

Comment: My doubt is if I can use this model output as a good model, and if this lines have any consequence on the final output. And if the negative binomial will be a good option for this type of data. Thanks

Comment: I am not sure how to be plainer. Try this: It looks pretty much like *exactly what you'd expect to see*, if the data were negative binomial. What did you think it should look like?

Comment: I wasn't sure if the lines of the residuals vs fitted values were correct. I added a plot residuals vs predicted values where I got the same lines with many negative predicted values, are these values correct? could I accept this? thanks!

Comment: With the one with negative predicted values *what was the actual model*? Can you show how this was obtained?

Comment: I updated the question; the actual model was the null model (null<-glm.nb(Sightings~offset(logEffortScale),data=l, link=log)) and the code for the plot was (plot(residuals(null)~predict(null)))

Comment: Ah. You're not getting what you imagine you're getting. See `?predict.glm` which explains that the default for the `type` argument is predictions on the scale of the linear predictor, not the observations. The linear predictor can easily be negative. Try `type="response"` in your call to `predict` ...

Comment: Thanks Glen_b, I didn't know that. I updated the final plot, and it looks much nicer.

Comment: The R package DHARMa will help you make more interpretable plots: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DHARMa/index.html > The 'DHARMa' package uses a simulation-based approach to create
> readily interpretable scaled (quantile) residuals for fitted
> generalized linear mixed models.

Answer (score 4):

This sort of pattern is to be expected with count data and log-links. The count data makes the residual vs fitted plot have "lines" diagonally across it (and gaps between), corresponding to counts of 0, 1, 2,... and the log-link makes those "lines" curved.

So you will expect to see this with Poisson and negative binomial regression and log links if the typical count is fairly small, in particular with simple models (such as say one continuous predictor, or one continuous predictor and a factor with few levels).

So nothing seems to be amiss, at least not from the appearance of the plots.